# Can't get Google Protocol Buffer to compile

Tags: python, terminal, protocol-buffers, gtfs

I am following the google python tutorial for the protocol buffer, I have been able to successfully do everything up until the compiler.

https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/pythontutorial

The tutorial says the following:

*Now run the compiler, specifying the source directory (where your application's source code lives – the current directory is used if you don't provide a value), the destination directory (where you want the generated code to go; often the same as $SRC_DIR), and the path to your .proto. In this case, you...:*

*protoc -I=$SRC_DIR --python_out=$DST_DIR $SRC_DIR/addressbook.proto*

Say I have the addressbook.proto file located on my desktop and the desktop is also where I want the generated code to go, what should the above terminal command then look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are working under linux, you could set the $SRC_DIR variable like this (note that I dropped the DST_DIR):

```
SRC_DIR="/home/USERNAME/Desktop" protoc -I=$SRC_DIR --python_out=$SRC_DIR $SRC_DIR/addressbook.proto
```

Or you could replace every $SRC_DIR and $DST_DIR with "/home/USERNAME/Desktop" (this will work on windows too if you instead use the path to your Desktop..)

Answer (score 1):

In the future, if you don't want to compile Python proto classes yourself, you might consider the gtfs-realtime-bindings PyPI package, which provides pre-generated Pythong language bindings for GTFS-realtime.  More details at:

https://github.com/google/gtfs-realtime-bindings/tree/master/python

(Full disclosure: I maintain these packages)